# How to log into the Stack Exchange app with a different Google account?

Tags: support, bug, mobile-app

Somehow, I logged into the Stack Exchange app with another of my accounts on Google. I've tried to log out and log back in again but the app doesn't ask me which of my Google accounts it should log into anymore.

This is obviously a bug which should be fixed, but is there a workaround?

Comment: Android? Clear the data for the app.